# if/else statement didn't work inside function

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

Hi I just writing a simple code to calculate the cheapest price by unit of eggs depend on the quantity coming in the box(12pcs,18pcs or 20pcs)

```
// var quantity of eggs//
var docena="12";
var dieciocho="18";
var veinte="20";
//type price by quantity//
var precio_docena=prompt("dozen");
var precio_dieciocho=prompt("eighteen");
var precio_veinte=prompt("twenty");
//calculate price by unit//
var precio_unidad12=precio_docena/docena;
var precio_unidad18=precio_dieciocho/dieciocho;
var precio_unidad20=precio_veinte/veinte;

//shows cheaper//    

if
(precio_unidad12<precio_unidad18 && precio_unidad12<precio_unidad20){
    document.getElementById("minimun").innerHTML="dozen";
}
else if
(precio_unidad12>precio_unidad18 && precio_unidad12<precio_unidad20){
    document.getElementById("med").innerHTML="eighteen";
}
else 
{
    document.getElementById("highest").innerHTML="twenty";
}
```

when i run that works like i wanted but if i enclose the if else statement into a function just show me the else statement only (just shows twenty not matter who statement is true)

```
//var quantities of eggs//
var docena="12";
var dieciocho="18";
var veinte="20";
//type price by quantity//
var precio_docena=prompt("dozen");
var precio_dieciocho=prompt("eighteen");
var precio_veinte=prompt("twenty");
//calculate price by unit//
var precio_unidad12=precio_docena/docena;
var precio_unidad18=precio_dieciocho/dieciocho;
var precio_unidad20=precio_veinte/veinte;

 //shows cheaper//   
function calculate(){
if
(precio_unidad12<precio_unidad18 && precio_unidad12<precio_unidad20){
    document.getElementById("minimun").innerHTML="dozen";
}
else if
(precio_unidad12>precio_unidad18 && precio_unidad12<precio_unidad20){
    document.getElementById("med").innerHTML="eighteen";
}
else 
{
    document.getElementById("highest").innerHTML="twenty";
}
}
calculate();
```

what can i fix to this work inside of a function i need to call the function in the future
thanks and sorry English its my second language

Answer (score 0):

It's happening When The Elements You Try To Load By IDs are Not Loaded when the function triggers

You Can Use onLoad Event Attribute in Body Element to prevent This

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>
    </head>



<body onload="calculate();">

    <div id="minimun">a</div>
    <div id="med">b</div>
    <div id="highest">c</div>
    
</body>
    <script>
        //var quantities of eggs//
        var docena="12";
        var dieciocho="18";
        var veinte="20";
        //type price by quantity//
        var precio_docena=prompt("dozen");
        var precio_dieciocho=prompt("eighteen");
        var precio_veinte=prompt("twenty");
        //calculate price by unit//
        var precio_unidad12=precio_docena/docena;
        var precio_unidad18=precio_dieciocho/dieciocho;
        var precio_unidad20=precio_veinte/veinte;

         //shows cheaper//   
        function calculate(){
            if
            (precio_unidad12<precio_unidad18 && precio_unidad12<precio_unidad20){
                document.getElementById("minimun").innerHTML="dozen";
            }
            else if
            (precio_unidad12>precio_unidad18 && precio_unidad12<precio_unidad20){
                document.getElementById("med").innerHTML="eighteen";
            }
            else 
            {
                document.getElementById("highest").innerHTML="twenty";
            }
        }

    </script>

</html>
```

You Can Check Your JS Code is Working or Not By replacing document.getElementById(); to alert(); like this

```
        function calculate(){
            if
            (precio_unidad12<precio_unidad18 && precio_unidad12<precio_unidad20){
                alert("dozen");
            }
            else if
            (precio_unidad12>precio_unidad18 && precio_unidad12<precio_unidad20){
                alert("eighteen");
            }
            else 
            {
                alert("twenty");
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my script src comand its after the divs items and happen the same if i change innerhtml for console.log at soon i can i try with alert